# Creating a dataframe from function that returns 8 values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

```
for image_file in glob.iglob('C:\\pathtofolder\\*.jpg'):
    HP, HR, Glass, EV, FV, Glared, S, L = faceApp(image_file)
    faceDeets = pd.DataFrame({'HP': [HP], 'HR': [HR], 'Glass': [Glass], 'EV': [EV], 'FV': [FV], 'Glared': [Glared], 'S': [S], 'L': [L]})
    time.sleep(5)
```

I would like to create a dataframe for each image_file. The above code only returns the values for one image. [DataFrame created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHcnq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try that:

```
data = []
for image_file in glob.iglob('C:\\pathtofolder\\*.jpg'):
    data.append(faceApp(image_file))
    time.sleep(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['HP', 'HR', 'Glass', 'EV', 'FV', 'Glared', 'S', 'L'])
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
I got this TypeError

Comment: Thanks again! I am really stuck on this. Now there is this error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8, 1), indices imply (8, 8)

Comment: I tried to fix it with     data = np.array(data).reshape(1,8)  and this returns only one row

Comment: My bad! Really sorry, I forgot to append data... It should work now. If it doesn't work, I'm fired :)